# Aptitude ( Time and work based question (Wipro)) )

Tags: aptitude

A and B can do a piece of work in 30 days while B and C can do the same the work in 24 days and C and A in 20 days. The work all together for 10 days when B and D leaves How many day more will A take to finish the work?

Comment: So many false assumptions in this. What if the work is not parallelisable to three (or four, where did D come from) tracks? What about the additional communication overhead of adding more people to a team? If I give you two copies of The Mythical Man-Month can you read it in half the time?

Answer (score 0):

This is a math question, consider moving it to https://math.stackexchange.com/, but here you go:
let 1 be the amount of work, and let A,B and C be the daily work amount of A B and C respectively. What we know is:

```
1/30=A+B
1/24=B+C
1/20=A+C
```

Solving for A,B and C you get:
a = 1/48 and b = 1/80 and c = 7/240.
Then in 10 days the work done is:
10/48+10/80+70/240=0.625, so 0.375 remains, which is 18/48.
That means A will need 18 further days to complete the work.

Comment: The OP's question looks like something out of a quiz or homework assignment. And shows no effort, just the question. Perhaps not the best idea to directly answer such questions (as they are off-topic).